# Magento Onepage checkout error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: magento-1.7

Does anyone know what is causing this error in Magento Onepage Checkout?

I can't progress to the billing step when I click continue:

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null '

Shows in the error console.

I am using the default theme on the frontend but have a custom template for another store which doesn't have this issue.

I've searched and searched but cannot find a solution other than reinstall...

Can someone assist me please?

Comment: Are you sure the custom theme hasn't overwritten some code js files?

Comment: @AndrewThe custom theme is under the default theme but the fronted theme is still Base... Its almost impossible to debug this as the error doesn't tell me much

Comment: Do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: @Andrew http://uk-dev3.thanedirect.com I appreciate your efforts

Comment: can you please add the line of your code who give you that error ?!